# Translation of an article of Littlewood

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

I want to read the English translation of an article of Littlwood titled "Quelques conséquences de l'hypothese que la fonction $ζ (s)$ de Riemann n'a pas de zéros dans le demi-plan $ℜs> 1/ 2$." I suspect that there must be translation of this paper to english as it contains some important results regarding Riemann zeta functions. Any references?

Comment: Could it be https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/plms/s2-24.1.175

Comment: The article mentioned in the question was published on 1912 but the paper you mentioned was published on 1924.

Comment: you can find the 1912 article [here](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/31526#page/269/mode/1up) --- it's mainly equations, what little text there is you can just feed to DeepL or Google Translate.